# Converting log standard deviation in terms of the original units

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, logarithm

We run regression specifications of the form,

`lm(outcome_log_s ~ x1_s + x1_x^2)`

In which the outcome variable is logged and standardized. We want to be able to convey what, for example, a coefficient of ".1" on one of our covariates means is in terms of the original y-scale.  How would we go about doing this given standard deviation information from mean centered and log mean centered versions of the same variable

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could formulating it as having $Y$ as the outcome, $Z = \log(Y) - \overline{\log(Y)}$ and the model $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \beta_{i} X_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{p} \beta_{i+p} X_{i}^2$? Or do we have only linear dependence on $X$?

Comment: And when centering the outcome, is it done with the sample mean of true population mean? What happens at different observations? The centering is different?

Comment: Centering is done on the sample mean.  Not sure what you mean by "what happens at different observations."  The outcome is centered by taking (Y_i - Y_mean) for all observations.

Comment: The point is then to compare two (or more) observations from the same sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Additive changes in log imply multiplicative effect. The scaling of the output also plays a role as it changes the scale of the multiplicative effect. That is, if change of 1 in the units of $X$ corresponds to a change of 0.69 in the units of scaled log $Y$, then this implies $e^{0.69 \cdot \text{sd}(\log(Y))}$.

As standard deviation is not affected by centering, we can use `sd(data$outcome_log_m)` as the value of $\text{sd}(\log(Y))$. Thus, we get a multiplicative affect of $ e^{0.69 \cdot 0.8339012 } \approx 1.70$.

In terms of interpertation, this means 70% increase in the value measured.

## Explanation

Assume we transform the data as $$ Z_{i} = \frac{\log(Y_{i}) - \overline{\log(Y)}}{\text{sd}(\log(Y))}$$
and model it as 
$$ Z_i = \beta^{\top} X_i + \eta_{i}$$
where $\eta_{i}$ models the noise.

Assume that for a specific point $i$, $X_{i}$ changes to $X_{i,\varepsilon} = X_{i} + \varepsilon$, without affecting the value of $\eta$. This implies $$Z_{i,\varepsilon} - Z_{i} = \beta^{\top} \varepsilon.$$ On the other hand, assuming the mean and standard deviation are close to the true mean and standard deviation (so the $\varepsilon$ won't change them a lot), $$Z_{i,\varepsilon} - Z_{i} = \frac{\log(Y_{i,\varepsilon}) - \overline{\log(Y)}}{\text{sd}(\log(Y))} - \frac{\log(Y_{i}) - \overline{\log(Y)}}{\text{sd}(\log(Y))} = \frac{1}{\text{sd}(\log(Y))} \log\left(\frac{Y_{i,\varepsilon}}{Y_{i}}\right).$$
Together, they imply,
$$ \log\left(\frac{Y_{i,\varepsilon}}{Y_{i}}\right) = \beta^{\top}\varepsilon \cdot \text{sd}\left(\log(Y)\right)$$
which can be written as
$$ Y_{i,\varepsilon} = e^{\beta^{\top}\varepsilon \cdot \text{sd}\left(\log(Y)\right)} Y_{i}$$

Precise calculation would take into account the different sources of error - from the mean calculation, standard deviation calculation and estimation error to create a confedence interval.

Comment: Sorry -- I appear to still be struggling.  Can you explain a bit more how you get the line after the sentence: "which in turn implies...?"  How did you go from Z_ie - Z_i to log(Y_ie / Yi), and why do you multiply the right side by the sd(log(y))?  Pardon the ignorance.

Comment: See updates. I assumed that the sample size is large enough so that the affect of $Y_{i,\varepsilon}$ in the mean and sd is negligible. If it is not the case, we can make a more carefull analysis. 
Another way to analyze it, is to consider the difference between two observations in the same sample. This type of analysis require assumptions on the error $\eta$.

Comment: Hey tmrlvi. Quick question, do these calculations change if you include X and X^2 in your model (e.g. a polynomial term).  It seems that, in this case, the  amount that you add to X will be affected as you also have to increase by ^2

Comment: In fact, if we our model is $\beta_{1} X + \beta_{2} X^2$, then an $\epsilon$ change in $X$ would lead to a $(\left(\beta_{1}+2\beta_{2}X\right)\varepsilon+\beta_{2}\varepsilon^{2}) \cdot \text{sd}(\log(Y))$ change in $\log(Y)$. That is - the value of $X$ also plays a role.